# Access-rights at lower granularity than section?

Tags: user-groups, permissions

I would like to make a page where different groups of users would only have access to the entries created by their own group.

Now I can create a group and give it access to a certain section, but ideally I would like all groups to edit the same section, but different entries.

There is a "edit other people's entries" permission, but not on the group level.

Never satisfied, I would ALSO like to be able to limit visibility of the entries a user cannot edit, not just whether they can be edited/deleted?

There isn't a "can user view this" hook is there? Or a "visible by X,Y,Z" flag on posts I could set?

Thanks!

Comment: You want them to use Craft's control panel, right? Because you can have all this with front end forms quite easily.

Comment: What's the criteria for which entries a user group can edit if not the entry's section? Categories? A drop-down field? Who creates the entries, you're only speaking of editing.

Comment: @carlcs - it's all a bit open atm, but ideally through the CP - but new forms is an option. I was thinking that each group can only edit the entries they created themselves.

Comment: My colleague just suggested that maybe a craft multi-site type setup, with one entire DB for each group may be able to work. Apologies this isn't the best thought out question :)